# Angularjs with browsersync post method send as options

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, browser-sync

I have an Angular 1.6.4 application using Browser-sync with gulp. When uploading the Browser-sync with the command "gulp server" and when making a post request in a webapi 2.0 c #, the request is sent as options.

Error:
**OPTIONS ... 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)**

**XMLHttpRequest connot load ... Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405**

Browser-sync

```
browserSync.init({
        notify: false,
        cors: true,
        port: 6543,
        server: {
            baseDir: config.dir.src,
            routes: {
                "/bower_components": "bower_components"
            },
            middleware: function(req, res, next) {
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                next();
            }
        }
    });
```

Angular JS request

```
$http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/Teste/TesteController/Cadastrar',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    data: envelope
                }).then(function (response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    }, function (error) {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    });
```

Webapi

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Teste(Teste responsavel)
    {
        var saida = MontarSaida(_service.Cadastrar(responsavel, _serviceUsuario));
        return Ok(ResponseContent.Create("Ok", null, saida, 1));
    }
```

Resolve: add in web.config

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browser (more specifically Chrome) usually tries to do an OPTIONS call before doing a post. That to make sure the CORS headers are in order. This error can occur if you are not handling the OPTIONS call in your API controller:

```
public void Options() { }
```

Also, the OPTIONS method should be enabled

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE" />
```

Comment: S.Dav, thank for help, but i fix this error add in web.config :<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />

Answer (score 0):

On Stask there are a lot of answer.
Try to look for CORS

I hope this sheme would be helpfull for you
https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png

P.S. You need to specify behavior for CORS in your base controller on backend